# How to get css file to href of link from npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've installed a package from npm.

```
npm install lightgallery
```

I need to fill href of link with this package's css file directory. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/lightgallery/css/lightgallery.css" />
```

But I can't reach the files in `node_modules`. I'm using `express.static`, maybe this problem stems about static files...

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))
```

How can I serve that file and use it in link href?

Comment: `node_modules` is spelled incorrectly in your href attribute

Comment: No, it's not about it. I fixed it but this problem is about different situation.

Comment: Is `node_modules` inside `assets`? (Because that seems unlikely, and a rather obvious reason why the route wouldn't find it).

Comment: @Quentin no, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solve it!

I served node_modules like this:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'))
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be making your entire node_modules folder public. Use a bundler to generate your static CSS file in a sensible place.